# Appending [(String, Double)] in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, string

I'm still learning Swift, and I am learning this Stock Web Service tutorial that I found in the Web. I am quite stuck in appending the extracted values from the service to my array. Below is the sample code.

Array Initialization

```
private var sampleStocks: [(String, Double)] = [("GOOG", +2.2), ("YHOO", +3.22), ("AAPL", -4.1)];
```

Appending

```
let values = (notification.userInfo as! Dictionary<String,NSArray>)
    let stocksReceived:NSArray = values[constantNotifUpdate]!;
    sampleStocks.removeAll();
    for quote in stocksReceived {
        let quoteDict:NSDictionary = quote as! NSDictionary;
        var changeInPercentString = quoteDict["ChangeinPercent"] as! String;
        let changeInPercentStringClean: String = changeInPercentString.substring(to: changeInPercentString.index(before: changeInPercentString.endIndex));
        var me: [(String,Double)] = [(quoteDict["symbol"] as! String, Double(changeInPercentStringClean))];
        sampleStocks.append(me);


    }
```

I always got this error of "Cannot convert of type [(String, Double)] to expected argument type (String, Double)".

May you please help me and give me a short run through?

Comment: You need to use sampleStocks.append(contentsOf: me)

Comment: If you really want to **learn Swift** look for better tutorials for example those which suggest a custom struct rather than a tuple and which don't use semicolons and `NSDictionary / NSArray` and redundant type annotations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var me: [(String,Double)]` is an Array. What you need is a tuple. Declare the `me` variable like this:

```
var me: (String,Double) = (quoteDict["symbol"] as! String, Double(changeInPercentStringClean)!);
```

Comment: Hi max, thanks for the reply. So I did 'code var me: (String,Double) = [quoteDict["symbol"] as! String, Double(changeInPercentStringClean)];' and I have an error _Contextual type (String, Double) cannot be used with array literal_

Answer (score 0):

You can use in swift 3.0.2 by:

```
sampleStocks.append(contentsOf: me)
```

or

```
var me: (String,Double) = (quoteDict["symbol"] as! String, Double(changeInPercentStringClean))
sampleStocks.append(me)
```